# Why is type of property name and its type separated?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is a minimalistic example:

```
type Type = {
  foo: 'FOO';
  bar: 'BAR';
};

export function fn<T extends keyof Type>(key: T, value: Type[T]) {
  return {
    key,
    value,
  };
}

type Ret = ReturnType<typeof fn>;
```

Now `Ret` is evaluated to:

```
type Ret = {
    key: keyof Type;
    value: "FOO" | "BAR";
}
```

How to achieve this?

```
type Ret = {
    key: "foo";
    value: "FOO";
} | {
    key: "bar";
    value: "BAR";
}
```

Comment: Beware that your function can be called like `fn<'foo' | 'bar'>('foo', 'BAR')` and this will type-check without a compilation error. So the return type inferred by Typescript is actually correct.

Comment: Even if you change `fn()` so it can only accept arguments like `...[key, value]: ["foo", "FOO"] | ["bar", "BAR"]`, the compiler cannot follow the correlation between the `key` and `value` parameters through the destructuring/restructuring; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Forcing the compiler to go through the different cases like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVVBW) gives you the "right" return type but it's redundant and no longer generic in the way you want when you actually call it.

Comment: But the straightforward answer to your question is: when manipulating a generic function type, the compiler tends to just plug in the constraints for any generic type parameters; there are no higher kinded types or generic values of the sort needed to represent `ReturnType<typeof fn>` precisely, so the compiler gives you something less precise but easy to represent.  Not sure how/if to flesh this out into an actual answer.